# Phonegap - iOS filetransfer not working with authorization header

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to upload an image captured from the camera to a server.  The method below works great for any Android devices, but for some reason, it's failing on iOS.  It's returning a 401 error, which doesn't make sense:

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="files[]";
    options.fileName = 'image_' + obj.id + '.jpg';
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    var params = new Object();
    params.headers = {
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + loginCreds
    }

    options.params = params;
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, CONTEXT+'URL/files", 
        function(r){
            alert('Finished upload!');
            $.mobile.loading( 'hide' );  
        }, 
        function(error){
            console.log(error.http_status);
            alert('Error uploading image: ' +error.http_status+ ' and code - ' +error.code); 
            $.mobile.loading( 'hide' );  
        }, 
        options, true);
```

I know there was an issue setting headers in iOS, but I thought that was fixed as of Phonegap 1.9.0.  Am I doing something wrong here?

I checked the server logs, and it seems like the authorization header is just simply not being set in iOS.  Strange...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So figured this one out after a whole day of wrestling with it.  So it turns out, Android and iOS differ on how they can take the headers parameter.

Android:

```
var params = new Object();
params.headers = {Authorization: 'Basic ' + loginCreds};
options.params = params;
```

OR

```
options.headers = {Authorization: 'Basic ' + loginCreds};
```

iOS:

```
options.headers = {Authorization: 'Basic ' + loginCreds};
```

Hope this saves someone somewhere some headaches...

Comment: You saved me from banging my head against the wall. Thank you!

Comment: It saves a lot of headaches

Comment: It saves my lots of time